# Automatically creating tables in BigQuery

Tags: json, database, google-bigquery, transfer

I created a transfer that loads data from an Amazon S3 bucket to my Google Cloud daily. The Google Cloud bucket contains a folder with more subfolders that contain application/octet-stream "files". I can manually create tables (in json) using them in BigQuery.

However, there is lots of them and I was wondering if it is possible to automatically create them. I always use the automatic schema and they are in json. I don't change any other settings. Is it possible to do this in the UI, and if not, how do I do this in the console?

Comment: You should probably clarify your question: do you want to automatically load your JSON files into BQ as soon as they reach GCS, or do you want a shell command to load them at once ? ("do this in the UI or the console": that sounds manual + the console and the UI is actually the same, you probably meant Cloud Shell)

Comment: As soon as the file is loaded into GC, I want a table in BQ based on it. The format should be in json and the schema should be automatically detected.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions) which will be [triggered by file upload](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background#cloud-storage-example). Such cloud function can process uploaded file and create a table in BigQuery.